# How to change product title color in shop page if product has specific product tag (Woocommerce)?

Tags: php, functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, tags

How to make Woocommerce automatically change product title color for shop page if product has specific product tag (Woocommerce)?

Example: if products have tag "banana" or "melon", then products which have tags "banana" or "melon", their titles will be displayed yellow on product list page (shop area).

Comment: Welcome! Questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and should be asked on official WooCommerce support routes/forums.